# GCC: strange unresolved reference on function which doesn't used

Tags: c++, gcc, vtable

```
#include <iostream>

struct CL1
{
    virtual void fnc1();
    virtual void fnc2(); //not defined anywhere
};
void CL1::fnc1(){}

int main() {}
```

This gives an undefined reference error on fnc2, however it isn't used anywhere. Why is this happening? I tried to do it on Visual Studio and then it's linked successfully.

Comment: I would argue that the alleged VS behaviour is what is strange.

Comment: Don't reference it then. If it's not defined, you won't be using it anyway. Isn't there a #define in the header file for fnc2 that you can use to see if the function exists? You know, `#ifdef FNC2_H_INCLUDED`, stuff like that.

Comment: Virtual functions are always required to be defined. (Because the standard says so, and because the compiler may need to be able to put a pointer to it into the vtable.)

Comment: @juanchopanza Since CL1 is never used there's no particular need to generate its vtable; no diagnostic required.

Comment: Why don't add the implementation with an empty body in the class definition? That costs just one return statement and has the benefit of a clean interface. The secret knowledge that the function is not used is worthless in that case and your code is better maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc does not remove not used symbols by default at link time,
so for your class with virtual functions, it generate virtual table,
with pointers to each virtual function, and move this table to .rodata section,
so you should receive such error message:

```
g++ test10.cpp
/tmp/cc5YTcBb.o:(.rodata._ZTV3CL1[_ZTV3CL1]+0x18): undefined reference to `CL1::fnc2()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

You can enable garbage collection and link time, and you not receive
and errors:

```
$ g++ -O3 -O3 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -fipa-pta test10.cpp -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--as-needed
$
```

Comment: Why should `CL1::fnc2` not be used? The virtual function table for `CL1` should have a reference to the function.

Comment: @harper `CL1` not used in the code at all, linker can remove all its function in optimization mode

Comment: So `int main() {}` is  real code?? In that case I would recommend to remove the class declaration from the source code by removing the corresponding `#include`.

Comment: @harper Have no idea, I work with code that TS provided.

Comment: It should be clarified that the code causes undefined behaviour, regardless of compiler settings

Comment: @M.M Why undefined behavior? According to this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options, manual not point any undefined behaviour in section about `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections`.

Comment: @user1034749 the C++ standard says what is defined and what isn't